# Cannot access up folder with PHP DirectoryIterator

Tags: php, directory, dir

I try to access an up folder.

The website folders are: you can also see the picture of the main folder here:
http://i58.tinypic.com/15odxl1.png

```
|
| - layout/(contains mainpic.php)
| - style/(contains css styles)
| - wallpapers/ (more folders here - sports, abstract, cartoon etc)
| - index.php
```

In the "mainpic.php" file I wrote this to access "Sports" folder in the up folder "wallpapers".

My code:

```
<?php
$firstPath="../wallpapers/Sports";
$file=new DirectoryIterator($firstPath);

echo "<ul>";

recurseImage($file);

function recurseImage($path)
{
    $dir=new DirectoryIterator($path);
 while ($dir->valid())
  {
     $file=$dir->current();
     echo "<li> <img src='".$file->getFilename().".jpg'></img>";
 $dir->next();
 }


echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

But when i execute the file, it shows me a php error which says that "The path was not found".

I tried to access the only main folder "wallpaper" like this:

```
$firstPath="wallpapers";
```

and it works even i didn't put the `..` before the path!

Comment: why you use DirectoryIterator ? what for ?

Comment: I'm a beginner..I'm now learning the "DirectoryIterator" class.. Is there another option?

Comment: Yes, there's another option you can try it out, check my answer. Hope it'll useful to you. and for your learning too... :)

Answer (score 0):

If your mainpic.php is included in file above it's folder you should try to declare absolute path. Try:

```
$firstPath= __FILE__"../wallpapers/Sports";
```

Comment: 1. I think you wanted to use `__DIR__` not `__FILE__` 2. You missed the concatenation dot

Comment: Yep, better try: `$firstPath= dirname(__FILE__) . "/../wallpapers/Sports";`

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is include in your index or else, try: `$firstPath="wallpapers/Sports";`

Comment: It shows me the main folder files..i need the "Sports" folder inside the "wallpaper" folder only..

Answer (score 0):

DirectoryIterator it self is a class provides a simple interface for viewing the contents of filesystem directories.

I suggest you to try a h5a1 directory listing. You can get it in [here](http://larsjung.de/h5ai/). It's a simple, From my point of view, this is a **nice option** for sharing files. Because you are using the built in Apache server, there's no need to install more stuff (no overhead) or even have extra daemons running just to serve the files. You just take advantage of what you already have, and improve upon it. It have a lot of *free functionality*

You can check the demo in [here](http://larsjung.de/h5ai/demo/).

Hope you get interested to using that.. :)

Answer (score -1):

"I tried to access the only main folder "wallpaper" like this: $firstPath="wallpapers"; and it works! even i didn't put the ".." before the path!"

that means your 'wallpapers' and your script are on the same folder. try

```
$firstPath="./wallpapers/Sports";
```

Comment: I know and that's wierd because they ARE NOT.